# XSLT issue with displaying very large numbers in for-each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

For some reason when I do an `xsl:for-each` on elements that have a very large number like 2394010512, `xsl:value-of` will not display the value.  It will display it outside of the for each loop though.  I am baffled by this.  I am using XSLT 1.0

I have tried `format-number()`. I have tried `string()`. Nothing helps

EDIT:
XML

```
<Response>
  <Files>
    <File>
      <FileID>
        123456
      </FileID>
      <Size>
        2394010512
      </Size>
    </File>
  </Files>
</Response>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="Files/File">
 File:<xsl:value-of select="FileID"/>|<xsl:value-of select="Size"/><br></br>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If I just do `<xsl:value-of select="Files/File/Size"/>` this displays fine

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Post a small example of your XML and the XSLT. A guess is that what you think you are selecting is not matching (due to namespaces or case sensitivity) and built-in templates are matching outside of your for loop and displaying the value. Though, cannot help without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: posted XML and XSLT. so the issue is that because of the large value in the Size element its not displaying anything in the loop.  If I make the value in the Size element smaller, it will display the values in the loop

Comment: Can you post a complete XSLT stylesheet that demonstrates the problem? Sometimes the issue occurs in other than the place you think it does. Also, can you show the output you are actually getting? Thank you.

Comment: Works for me. Produces:`             File:
                123456
            |
                2394010512
            <br/>
`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own.  I messed up with some syntax and casing.
thanks for looking at this